# Incorrect sum() result mysql with group by

Tags: mysql

I've problem with the result of sum(). please take a look at this var_dump()

```
                array(6) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#21 (5) {
            ["user_id"]=>
            string(2) "52"
            ["barang_id"]=>
            string(2) "18"
            ["jml_finish"]=>
            string(3) "120"
            ["harga_pasar"]=>
            string(6) "250000"
            ["jml_pendapatan_sales"]=>
            string(8) "30000000"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#23 (5) {
            ["user_id"]=>
            string(2) "54"
            ["barang_id"]=>
            string(2) "12"
            ["jml_finish"]=>
            string(3) "550"
            ["harga_pasar"]=>
            string(5) "25000"
            ["jml_pendapatan_sales"]=>
            string(8) "12500000"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#24 (5) {
            ["user_id"]=>
            string(2) "54"
            ["barang_id"]=>
            string(2) "18"
            ["jml_finish"]=>
            string(2) "50"
            ["harga_pasar"]=>
            string(6) "250000"
            ["jml_pendapatan_sales"]=>
            string(8) "12500000"
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#25 (5) {
            ["user_id"]=>
            string(2) "54"
            ["barang_id"]=>
            string(2) "11"
            ["jml_finish"]=>
            string(3) "100"
            ["harga_pasar"]=>
            string(5) "80000"
            ["jml_pendapatan_sales"]=>
            string(7) "8000000"
        }
        [4]=>
        object(stdClass)#26 (5) {
            ["user_id"]=>
            string(2) "54"
            ["barang_id"]=>
            string(2) "19"
            ["jml_finish"]=>
            string(3) "100"
            ["harga_pasar"]=>
            string(5) "70000"
            ["jml_pendapatan_sales"]=>
            string(7) "7000000"
        }
        [5]=>
        object(stdClass)#27 (5) {
            ["user_id"]=>
            string(2) "54"
            ["barang_id"]=>
            string(2) "24"
            ["jml_finish"]=>
            string(2) "25"
            ["harga_pasar"]=>
            string(5) "55000"
            ["jml_pendapatan_sales"]=>
            string(7) "1375000"
        }
    }
```

as you can see, I tried to multiply

> jml_finish * harga_pasar = jml_pendapatan_sales

and I think the second array is giving incorrect result, but the rest is correct.

here's my mysql code

```
        SELECT 
        
        user_id,
        barang_id,
        
        sum(kirim_barang_jml_finish) as jml_finish,
        max(table_barang.harga_pasar),
        max(table_barang.harga_pasar * kirim_barang_jml_finish) as jml_pendapatan_sales 
        
        from table_so_sales
        
        join table_barang on table_so_sales.barang_id = table_barang.id
        join table_user on table_so_sales.user_id = table_user.id
        join table_branch_lokasi on table_so_sales.branch_id_so = table_branch_lokasi.id
        
        WHERE kirim_barang_jml_finish > 0
        
        group by barang_id, user_id
        order by jml_pendapatan_sales desc
```

I tried to remove the max(), but still it gives incorrect value. Thank you in advance

**EDIT 1**
here's my table (more or less) :

**a. table_so_sales**

```
    id  barang_id   user_id     kirim_barang_jml_finish
    1       1              1        200
    2       2              1        200
    3       1              2        350
```

**b. table_barang**

```
   id   harga_pasar
    1   25000
    2   30000
```

**c. table_user**

```
    id  name
    1   Jhon
    2   Doe
```

p.s ignore table_branch_lokasi

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format (there are no `var_dump()`s in SQL, so that's pretty pointless).

Comment: I'm guessing you've got the wrong value at `max(table_barang.harga_pasar * kirim_barang_jml_finish)`, right? Unfortunately, that will never give you correct summation. Try change to `sum(table_barang.harga_pasar * kirim_barang_jml_finish)` and see what happen.

Comment: @FanoFN finally, you are correct! thank you! but what is the difference when use max(), sum(), or when not use both (just reguler arithmatic operation)

Comment: When you do `MAX()`, you'll only getting the highest value from the results row. Maybe I should post an answer to illustrate the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand the difference between `SUM()` and `MAX()`. Both are [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) and as per the documentation itself, it says

> SUM() - Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns NULL. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to sum only the distinct values of expr.

and

> MAX() - Returns the maximum value of expr. MAX() may take a string argument; in such cases, it returns the maximum string value

Now, let's take your `table_so_sales` data to do some exercises:

| id | barang_id | user_id | kirim_barang_jml_finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 350 |

First, let's do `SUM()`; particularly this query:

```
SELECT SUM(id), SUM(barang_id), SUM(user_id), SUM(kirim_barang_jml_finish)
FROM table_so_sales;
```

You'll get a result like this:

|  | SUM(id) | SUM(barang_id) | SUM(user_id) | SUM(kirim_barang_jml_finish) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| query results | 6 | 4 | 4 | 750 |
| operation illustrate | 1+2+3 | 1+2+1 | 1+1+2 | 200+200+350 |

However, when doing `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(id), MAX(barang_id), MAX(user_id), MAX(kirim_barang_jml_finish)
FROM table_so_sales;
```

you'll get:

|  | MAX(id) | MAX(barang_id) | MAX(user_id) | MAX(kirim_barang_jml_finish) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| query results | 3 | 2 | 2 | 350 |
| value in `[]` indicate the highest value in that column. | 1, 2, [3] | 1, [2], 1 | 1, 1, [2] | 200, 200, [350] |

Let's say I simplified your query to something like this:

```
SELECT  tss.barang_id,
        SUM(kirim_barang_jml_finish) AS jml_finish,
        MAX(tb.harga_pasar) highest_price,
        MAX(tb.harga_pasar * kirim_barang_jml_finish) AS max1,
        SUM(tb.harga_pasar * kirim_barang_jml_finish) AS sum1,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tb.harga_pasar * kirim_barang_jml_finish) AS data_in_rows
        
FROM table_so_sales tss
JOIN table_barang tb ON tss.barang_id=tb.id
GROUP BY tss.barang_id
```

That will return a result like this:

| barang_id | jml_finish | highest_price | max1 | sum1 | data_in_rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 550 | 25000 | 8750000 | 13750000 | 5000000, [8750000] |
| 2 | 200 | 30000 | 6000000 | 6000000 | 6000000 |

As you can see, data in `max1` and `sum1` differs simply because `MAX()` is getting the highest value of `tb.harga_pasar * kirim_barang_jml_finish` result while `SUM()` is adding up all of the result.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fc6a76dd46598d1362a2404a56834d6)

Hope this will help you understand more.

Comment: huge thank you for the solution and the easy explanation!